# Passing runtime arguments to pom.xml

Tags: maven, parameters, runtime

I have following piece of code in pom.xml

```
<groupId>ws.gp</groupId>
<artifactId>VZT</artifactId>
<myversion>${vzt-pom-version}</myversion>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

..and I am using maven release plugin when I try to pass a parameter during the run time I am getting error

```
BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The version could not be updated:
```

I tried following commands

```
mvn release:prepare -Dmyversion="2016May.0.0"
mvn release:perform -Dmyversion="2016May.0.0"
mvn release:prepare -Darguments="-Dmyversion=2016May.0.0"
mvn release:prepare "-Dws.gp-myversion=2016May.0.0"
```

Comment: if youre using a property for version, why are you trying to bump it?

Comment: This is more likely in Test Env vs Prod Env build...For Test env we use our Jenkins to generate the version which is passed to pom, but while building the artifact for Prod we want to manually pass the version#

Comment: im guessing the release plugin was just never designed to handle properties in versions (i'd be surprised if many plugins were). i'd suggest using something else to differentiate prod from test, like qualifiers.